# How to remove a test group from a build?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I have an app in iTunesConnect with version number 1.0 and build number N.

If I submit a new version with build number N+1, or N+2 etc. then test flight is automatically generating invitations to a group that had been previously added to 1.0 build number N-1.
I don't want it to do this, but I can't find anyway to either remove the group (there is an add new group button, but not a remove group) nor can I find a way to turn off automatic notifications to testers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over the group in the test flight UI. You can then remove the group by clicking on the red icon:

[image: Remove Group Icon]